# Show content of section in many other sections like css sprites

Tags: javascript

I have created very big "map" with many div-s. Now I want to show it in many other small sections. Sections, or windows, will show only part of the map.

Map will be changing after some events.

I could clone content of first section to other sections, but I think that is not good approach.

In css are image sprites. Is something like that in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific doing a question, if you can post some code it will help us to clarify what are exactly your needs. Anyway I will answer to your question:

> I could clone content of first section to other sections, but I think
>   that is not good approach.

Yeah, it isn't a good approach to clon content since you will lot of code lines that will do pretty much the same (never do that)

> "Map will be changing after some events"

Everytime you realize an event will happen you will need javascript for sure! Javascript it's a powerfull developing tool that will help you to improve the interaction of the user with your web application/system

You could use AJAX or JQuery. They will help you to simplify a bit the work you have to do with javascript. Use javascript to modify your css file. For example to show or hide a div when the user click a part of the map and so on.